# Capture output of when calling click command inside other command

Tags: python, python-click

I am calling `create` command inside `run` command, but can't capture output of `create`. `result` is None. Am I missing something?

What is the proper way to invoke other command and capture it's output?

```
   @click.command(
        'create')
    @click.pass_context
    def create(ctx):
            ...
            click.echo(click.style(response['name'], fg='green'))
            return response['name']


@click.command(
    'run')
@click.pass_context
def run(ctx):
    result = ctx.invoke(create)
```

Comment: Click commands don't return.  Any "output" is from `click.echo()`.

Comment: I know, but after `click.echo()`, there is `return response['name']`

Comment: This is not how click works, those commands do not return to the caller. There is exception handling and then a `sys.exit()` in the stack. Otherwise would the program give a proper exit code?

Comment: Got it, is there any other way to get output of previous command? What about passing it to context?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Click contexts are linked to the parent one, so I am just passing a value to the parent context.

```
@click.command('create')
@click.pass_context
    def create(ctx):
        ...
        click.echo(click.style(response['name'], fg='green'))
        if 'invoked_by_subcommand' in ctx.parent.__dict__:
            ctx.parent.return = response['output']


@click.command('run')
@click.pass_context
def run(ctx):
    ctx.invoked_by_subcommand = True
    result = ctx.invoke(create)
```